# Chrome browser in Android always renames downloaded file to Download.bin

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-7, downloading, chrome-for-android

I'm using a Nexus 7 device and whenever I download a file greater than 28MB, the Chrome browser renames it to Download.bin no matter what the name of the file. When I download a file less than 28MB, the type (jpg, for instance) remains intact but the name of the file is changed to "Download". When I use Firefox within android, the files are downloaded as expected no matter what the size. My hunch is that this is some security feature built into Chrome. The site is hosted by IIS 7.5 and I'm using the BOM with JavaScript to download the file. Any idea of a workaround for this so that Chrome downloads the files correctly? It works correctly on the desktop version of Chrome, but not the android version of Chrome. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Is it a personal file, or something we can also download. If you can share it, I would like to try and download it on my Chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a company website that I can't just share.  This is how I initiate the download through the BOM:                  var href = window.baseUrl + '/CloudStorage/Download?' + docIdsParam;
$(this).attr('href', href);

Comment: My wife's phone has this behavior a lot too, running Chrome 37.0.2062.117 on Android OS 4.4.4 with JavaScript version V8 3.27.34.15. Such an annoying loss of context. File names are valuable and renaming to restore information present in the browser is a fail for me. Just happened to me now with a jpeg image of 2.55MB.

Comment: Here's interesting behavior. If I click the link the file triggers a download as downloadfile.bin. If I click and hold to get the context menu and select "copy link" and then paste that into a new tab the file downloads with its name unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by the fact that the Android Chrome browser doesn't understand UTF-8 encoding.  I was UTF-8 encoding the file names since the desktop version of Chrome requires this.  It turns out that file names don't need to be UTF-8 encoded for non-ascii characters for the Android Chrome browser. I was able to successfully download a file using Android Chrome with Korean characters in it without encoding it with UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible there may be a problem with the site itself, or the browser. What you can do is to rename the .bin file to the expected filename. e.g. If you downloaded music.mp3 and the browser renamed it to anotherfilename.bin, just rename it to music.mp3 using a file manager.

You could also try other browsers. Give Dolphin, Boat Browser, or Opera a try and see if you still encounter the same problem.

Comment: geff, OP already wrote: *When I use Firefox within android, the files are downloaded as expected no matter what the size.* So he checked another browser, where it works correctly; so this issue must be chrome-specific.

Comment: As Izzy has noted, I have already tried a different browser and isolated the issue to the Android Chrome browser.